# resubscribe in DolphinDB

Tags: subscription, dolphindb

If a subscribing node in DolphinDB crashes, is there a way to automatically resubscribe in DolphinDB?

I wonder if there is a function like @reboot in cron that can enable automatic resubscription after the database restarts.

Answer (score 0):

If you need automatic reconnect, specify the parameter 'reconnect' in function 'subscribeTable'.